# Unable to Connect from Java to Kafka running in Docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Trying to stream MySql database to Kafka using Debezium.

So, in Docker Container, I have started Zookeeper, Kafka, MySQL Database, MySQL Command Line and Kafka Connect.

When I run any DML commands in the MySQL command line, I can able to see the change events in the watcher window which i started in the docker. So currently everything looks fine. please find below for the same.

[image: Docker Setup]

Now i am trying to consume the change events from the Java code which am able to see in the watcher window whenever i execute any DML commands in the MySQL Command Line. Please find below for Consumer.

```
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:29092");
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-first-consumer-group");
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
            Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
            ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<>();
            topics.add("dbserver1.inventory.customers");
            consumer.subscribe(topics);
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1L);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    System.out.println("Message received: " + record.value());
                }
                consumer.commitAsync();
            }
```

Unable to consume the data change events from the above consumer. Please let me know, if anything needs to be done.

Comment: Where is your Java consumer running? What error do you get from it?

Comment: both Java Consumer and Docker Setup is running on my Local machine. 
I tried with changing the property of BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG as below, and is working fine now. Able to consume the data changes.

properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "plaintext://localhost:9092");

and now my question has been turned to - how to get the initial contents of a Kafka Topic when it's connected to MySQL and streaming a table, as i can consume only the data changes ?

Comment: @Kola, welcome to SO. Can you post an answer, and ask a separate question for the initial contents question? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the property of BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG as below, and is working fine now. Able to consume the data changes.

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
```

and to consume the data changes

```
while (true) {
  ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000L);
  for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
    String payload = record.value();
    if(payload.contains("payload")) {
    JsonObject root = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(payload);
    root = root.getAsJsonObject("payload").getAsJsonObject("after");
   }
  }
  consumer.commitAsync();
}
```

It worked for me. :)

Comment: BTW, It'd be cleaner if you used Kafka Streams API

Answer (score 0):

The difference between what worked and didn't is the listener port that you accessed.

So either:

- 29092 was just wrong, and 9092 correct
- 29092 was bound to the advertised listener internal to the Docker network, and 9092 to `localhost` ([learn more](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/))

Comment: Yes, Exactly. Thanks Robin.